# suppress *Out[]* IPython printing, but not other printing

Tags: command-line, ipython

I am running some code in IPyton::

```
jrlab@jrlab-T150s:~$ ipython

In [1]: from IPython import get_ipython
   ...: ipython = get_ipython()
   ...: 
   ...: code = """
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...: 
   ...: print("bla")
   ...: 
   ...: plt.figure()
   ...: """
   ...: res = ipython.run_cell(code)
   ...: 
bla
Out[1]: <Figure size 640x480 with 0 Axes>
```

How do I disable the Out[1] printing, but not the printing commanded by the *print* statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`None` is not printed as output. So just append `; None` to any line whose output you wish to suppress:

```
In [1]: 1+2                                                                                                                                        
Out[1]: 3

In [2]: 1+2; None                                                                                                                                  

In [3]:
```

Comment: You don't even need the `None`.  Just end with `;`.